# Longitudinal toner stripes on printed page, that remain after drum replacement. (Brother DCP-9020cdw LED printer)

Tags: multi-function-printer, toner

Pages coming out of my **Brother DCP-9020cdw color LED printer** are dirty at several places.
Some time ago, I could temporarily get some improvement by dragging the cursor that cleans the corona wire of the black drum, but it didn't last.

Today, **I replaced the drum for the black color**, expecting it would fix the problem. Unfortunately **the problem persists** and at the right border of the page, the stripes are even more intense.

The one stripes quite at the left of the page are similar to the ones before the drum replacement, but at a slightly different location.

For toners and rollers, the printer is using only genuine new parts, coming from sealed packages, except the magenta toner cartridge which is a compatible one.

The level of the black cartridge is still ~70%.

<strike>**Should I replace the black toner cartridge or can something else cause the stripes?**</strike>

**Edit:** The problem likely comes from the fuser unit since the drum and black toner print flawlessly when inserted in another printer. See comments.

N.B. The lower roller of the fuser unit has been replaced few years ago by a compatible one. The quality of the prints has been good so far.

[image: printed page with unwanted vertical stripes of black toner]

Comment: You have offered many thoughts, making an answer just an opinion. Get the Printer serviced and use only genuine parts if you wish to keep it and use it.

Comment: The fuser probably needs replacement as well.

Comment: I had the opportunity to test the black drum/toner unit in a Brother DCP-9015cdw and the print quality was perfect ; this makes the problem comes from some other part, likely the fuser as ChanganAuto suggested. If the culprit was another drum, I assume the marks would be in the matching color.

Comment: @John: I always use genuine parts for drums and toners, but this printer was bought second hand and had some remaining compatible magenta toner that I used sucessfully during several years. The genuine fuser had a damaged lower fuser roller (with missing chunks of foam) that embossed the paper. I did replace this lower roller myself by a Chinese equivalent years ago, doing the servicing myself. The quality of the steel for the roller axis was lower, but the printer worked a few more years successfully. As genuine part, I could't find the roller without having to buy the whole fuser.